# Upper bound of a complex line integral

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, line-integrals

I have the following problem, to estimate an upper bound of the modulus of

$$\int\limits_C\frac{z+4}{z^3-1},$$

where $C$ is the circumference arc that passes from (2,0) to (0,2i) in the first quadrant, with origing as a center. I know that I have to use the estimation theorem, but I don't know how to bound

$$\frac{z+4}{z^3-1}.$$

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: On $C$ we have $|z|=2$, so $|z+4|\le6$.  See if you can continue from here.  (I am assuming that $C$ is an arc of a circle with centre at the origin, though you didn't actually say so.)

Comment: @David, thanks! It is so easy with only that comment!!!